# How to understand the realification of a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. A definition for the **realification** of $V$ is:

> The realification of $V$ uses the same addition, but allow scalar multiplication of real numbers only. Then $V$ becomes a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

I just cannot understand this definition:

(i) How to understand "allow scalar multiplication of real numbers only"? Will $V$ itself change or not?

(ii) Why is $V$ still a vector space after realification?

(iii) If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $V$, what will be the basis of $V$ after realification?

(iv) If $V$ is normed, will the norm change?

Comment: Make an example, e.g. $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R$-vector space. This is just $\Bbb R^2$, right? A basis would be $\{1,i\}$. As $\Bbb C$-vector space this is $1$-dimensional with basis $\{1\}$.

Comment: If I asked you to picture $\mathbb{C}$, there's a good chance that you would just picture the Cartesian plane with a unit length on the $y$-axis labelled $i$. That is, you are picturing $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$. The realification of $V$ is precisely this identification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The set $V$ itself does *not* change. And vector addition remains the same. What changes is that, when you consider the multiplication of a vector $v\in V$ by a scalar $\lambda$, you do it only when $\lambda$ is a real number.
2. Because the vector space axioms still hold. I suggest that you check that yourself.
3. No, never (unless $V=\{0\}$). For instance, $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb C^2$, but not of its realification. In fact, $(i,0)\in\Bbb C^2$, but you cannot write it as e linear combination with *real* coefficients of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.
4. No, it doesn't. The norm of $V$ is still a norm of the realification of $V$.

Comment: @Evan_Bradley: Just to complement what JC said, in his example $\mathscr{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has basis $\{(1,0),(i, 0),(0,1), (0,i)\}$. The usefulness if the r3ealification of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$, at least in functional analysis, is that it allows one to make extension of functionals by considering only their behavior on the realification of $V$ (the Hanh-Banach theorem for example. See Rudin, W. Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition, McGraw Hill, 1987, pp. 104-108.  In particular, Prop. 5.17.